# Is there any way to force WSO2 API Manager accept untrusted certificates?

Tags: ssl, wso2, certificate, endpoint, api-manager

I'm wondering if There is a way to force WSO2 API Manager accept untrusted certificates.
I want to use HTTPS endpoints in Publisher , And I do not want to import public certificate to client-truststore.jks and wso2carbon  every time.

I also tried to set HostnameVerifier to allowAll, but still same error happens.

> exception : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am working on WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable cert validation. But from 2.2.0 onwards, you can install certificates from UI.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Dynamic+SSL+Certificate+Installation

Comment: thank you so much, I updated to 2.2.0 , just one question , when I upload certificate , according to documents , it should be applied after 10 minutes , but it did not, even after 1 hour, what I missed?

Comment: Did you see any errors in the log while installing the cert?

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I didn't see any errors , everything looks good,The certificate applied only if I restart api manager.I don't understand if it is a bug in api manager new version 2.2 or I am missing some configurations?

Comment: I hope you're using a fresh 2.2.0 pack and you didn't copy any config files from 2.1.0. Yes?

Comment: Yes exactly, I didn't copy anything from 2.1.0 . I tried various ways but still no success.

Comment: Hi Bee, is it still like this in 3.2.0? We terminate SSL at the load balancer and wish to turn off SSL to Publisher

Comment: Using Google Cloud, and it was easy to configure the load balancer to use SSL for the internal connection from load balancer to WSO2 instance. Thanks